# connecting to firestore emulator from java admin sdk

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am trying to connect to firestore emulator from inside my java application, without much success.

```
FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault())
            .setDatabaseUrl("localhost:8082")

            .setProjectId("xxx")
            .build();
    var app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    Firestore db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore(app);
    final ApiFuture<WriteResult> update = db.collection("users").document().set(Map.of("test", "mest"));
    try {
        final WriteResult writeResult = update.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This simply tries to connect to firebase, disregarding the database url.

I looked at the node sdk, which has a `emulator` method and database settings, but they don't exist on Java side.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Firebase Admin SDK (Java)**, you can use following code to connect to **Local Emulator Suite** without setting the FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST environment variable:

```
import com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.internal.EmulatorCredentials;

FirestoreOptions firestoreOptions = FirestoreOptions.newBuilder()
    /* 
      TODO: replace with host at which your emulator is running
    */
    .setEmulatorHost("localhost:8080")
    .build();

FirebaseOptions firebaseOptions = FirebaseOptions.builder()
    .setCredentials(new EmulatorCredentials())
    /* 
      setting valid project-id is IMPORTANT;
      otherwise, data will not be visible inside Emulator UI
    */
    .setProjectId("[YOUR_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID]")
    .setFirestoreOptions(firestoreOptions)
    .build()

FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(firebaseOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore#admin_sdks):

> The Firebase Admin SDKs automatically connect to the Cloud Firestore emulator when the FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST environment variable is set:
>
> export FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:8080"

So I guess it doesn't matter what host you pass, so long as this environment is present?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the database link
You could try

```
.setDatabaseUrl("http://localhost:8082")
```

It worked for me.

**LATER EDIT**

Use

```
.setDatabaseUrl("http://localhost:8082?ns=fake-project-id")
```

The lack of the last part would trigger other errors later on websockets.